# libgmail login() runs with error

Tags: python, mechanize, libgmail

I just installed libgmail on CentOS 5, python 2.6 with easy_install. There was a problem, until i installed mechanize manually. After that easy_install said OK and i wrote 1st test program from the sample i googled:

```
    import libgmail

    ga = libgmail.GmailAccount("someaccount@gmail.com", "mypassword")
    ga.login()
    folder = ga.getMessagesByFolder('inbox')

    for thread in folder:
      print thread.id, len(thread), thread.subject
      for msg in thread:
        print "  ", msg.id, msg.number, msg.subject
        print msg.source
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gm.py", line 4, in <module>
    ga.login()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/libgmail.py", line 305, in login
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/libgmail.py", line 340, in _retrievePage
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mechanize/_request.py", line 31, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mechanize/_rfc3986.py", line 62, in is_clean_uri
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

It seems, i get a problem not with my python code, but with libgmail installation. Any clues, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libgmail is deprecated and has stopped developing, since gmail started offering imap access.

Use `imaplib` or similar ([`twisted.mail`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedMail) comes to mind, example code [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/examples/imap4client.py)).